# CRM 2015 OnLine - Request for the permission SecurityPermission failed

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, securityexception, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm trying to generate a PDF in memory to send it to a WS. This PDF should be created in memory (Stream) and in the Microsoft CRM "cloud" in a plugin code.
Is this possible?

In the plugin (already coded and deployed) I have this lines, the 3th fails

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
PdfPage pdfPage = pdf.AddPage();

XGraphics graphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage); //<-- ERROR
```

is this line of code trying to access a resource in the cloud that is not permitted/available?

this is the error:

> Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): Plugins8.Plugin: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

any ideas?

Comment: In my case it now turned out to be Serialization: In my plugin I serialize an Entity to Xml and this doesn't seem to be possible in Sandboxed plugins. I can still use Streams so this could be ruled out as the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using **PDFsharp** and you have its libraries merged into your plugin assembly using **ILMerge**.

If so, the SecurityException can be caused by PDFsharp using GDI+. In partial trusted app domains drawing graphics with GDI+ is not allowed. You can however compile PDFsharp for WPF. Try compiling PDFsharp with directives `WPF` plus (maybe) `SILVERLIGHT`.